# Where to store config for Windows service

Tags: windows, configuration, windows-services, appdata

I am developing a Windows service that uses a `config.json` file to store its configuration. When I developed it without a service, I stored the data in `%APPDATA%\companyname\product`.

Now I am switching to real Windows service. When is run it as a service, the path points to `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\company\product`. But I can't find my file in there. I tested it with the Explorer and a command prompt (as administrator). How can I access my configuration.

Is that the best place to put my configuration file?

Comment: Is the service able to read its config?

Comment: Yes, it can. The config is stored permanent. After restarting the service it is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting my configuration in `C:\ProgramData`.